# Python - How can I convert a special character to the unicode representation?

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, unicode, unicode-escapes

In a dictionary, I have the following value with equals signal:

```
{"appVersion":"o0u5jeWA6TwlJacNFnjiTA=="}
```

To be explicit, I need to replace the `=` for the unicode representation `'\u003d'` (basically the reverse process of `[json.loads()][1]`). How can I set the unicode value to a variable without store the value with two scapes (`\\u003d`)?.

I've tryed of different ways, including the enconde/decode, repr(), unichr(61), etc, and even searching a lot, cound't find anything that does this, all the ways give me the following final result (or the original result):

```
'o0u5jeWA6TwlJacNFnjiTA\\u003d\\u003d'
```

Since now, thanks for your attention.

**EDIT**

When I debug the code, it gives me the value of the variable with 2 escapes. The program will get this value and use it to do the following actions, including the extra escape. I'm using this code to construct a json by the `json.dumps()` and the result returned is a unicode with 2 escapes.

Follow a print of the final result after the JSON construction. I need to find a way to store the value in the var with just one escape.

[image]

I don't know if make difference, but I'm doing this to a custom BURP Plugin, manipulating some selected requests.

Here is an image of my POC, getting the value of the var.

[image]

Comment: Do you need 'o0u5jeWA6TwlJacNFnjiTA\u003d\u003d' as an output?

Comment: No, I'm manipulating the data and constructing with `json.dumps()`. JkShaw  showed a solution that just need to do a replace in the code, but doesn't works because the JSON function will keep the extra escape.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The extra backslash is not actually added, The Python interpreter uses the repr() to indicate that it's a backslash not something like \t or \n when the string containing \ gets printed:
I hope this helps:

```
>>> t['appVersion'] = t["appVersion"].replace('=', '\u003d')

>>> t['appVersion']
'o0u5jeWA6TwlJacNFnjiTA\\u003d\\u003d'

>>> print(t['appVersion'])
o0u5jeWA6TwlJacNFnjiTA\u003d\u003d

>>> t['appVersion'] == 'o0u5jeWA6TwlJacNFnjiTA\u003d\u003d'
True
```

Comment: I've tryed to do this way, but doesn't work. When I debug the code, it gives me the value of the variable as you showed, with 2 escapes. The program will get this value and use it to do the following actions, including the extra escape. I'm using this code to construct a json by the `json.dumps()` and the result returned is a unicode with 2 escapes.

Comment: @IgorRuanGarcia please provide what you do, with exact input and output expected and the following actions and their input and output, such that i can help you better.

Comment: I've tryed to detail better my question editing it. If you have more questions, please inform to we try together solve this problem. Thanks since now for your help!